# Python thread remaining in Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

To sumup my problem, I have made this little program which does nothing but create a series of threads which print something and should destroy themselves.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def mythread(i):
    print 'i %s \n' % i
    sleep(1)

def start():
    i = 1
    while 1:
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
        pool.apply_async(mythread, (i,))
        sleep(5)

# ----------------------
#          Main
# ----------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

But when I run this program under the name of test.py, the command **ps aux -T** to get the list of process show something I did not expected.

```
10:04 azerty@3RMQP32 ~/Bureau $ ps aux -T | grep test | grep -v grep
azerty  9613  9613  0.2  0.0 322616  7520 pts/19   Sl+  10:04   0:00 python test.py
azerty  9613  9614  0.0  0.0 322616  7520 pts/19   Sl+  10:04   0:00 python test.py
azerty  9613  9615  0.0  0.0 322616  7520 pts/19   Sl+  10:04   0:00 python test.py
azerty  9613  9616  0.0  0.0 322616  7520 pts/19   Sl+  10:04   0:00 python test.py
azerty  9613  9617  0.0  0.0 322616  7520 pts/19   Sl+  10:04   0:00 python test.py
```

I was expected 2 processus for the first second, the main and the thread then only the main in sleep. Finally, one thread would pop for 1 sec every 5 sec and kill himself right after. But I don't observe that. The main processus generate 4 sub threads which never die and 5 seconds later,
4 new are created until I kill everything.

How can I make sure that at least the sub threads will finish themselves when they reach the end of their functions. I can't **join()** on the main because I need it to run and to launch threads continuously.

Thank you,

Comment: probably unrelated but creating a new thread pool of 1 every iteration is definitely not the way threadpools should be used. you should use a.. pool of more than one thread and iteratively apply_async from that pool (as opposed to creating a new pool each time)

Comment: I get that, but is there is another way to start threads the way I have to do it ?

Comment: increase the `processes` count and move it out of the loop

Comment: Threads in thread pools aren't supposed to be killed. They are reused. I guess that's the reason